How to generate a directory tree iteratively, implemented in Python?
I have already implemented generating a directory tree using recursion:
import os
import re
import hashlib

PIPE = "│"
ELBOW = "└──"
TEE = "├──"
PIPE_PREFIX = "│   "
SPACE_PREFIX = "    "

root_dir = ""
tree = []

def extract_number(file_name):
    match = re.search(r"\d+", file_name)
    return int(match.group()) if match else float("inf")

def get_md5(file_path):
    hasher = hashlib.md5()
    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(8192), b""):
            hasher.update(chunk)
    return hasher.hexdigest()

def tree_head():
    tree.append(f"{root_dir}{os.sep}")
    tree.append(PIPE)

def get_entries(directory):
    with os.scandir(directory) as entries:
        entries = list(entries)

        entries = [entry for entry in entries if entry.name != ".DS_Store"]

        entries = sorted(entries, key = lambda entry: (entry.is_file(), extract_number(entry.name)))

    return entries

def tree_body(directory, prefix = ""):
    entries = get_entries(directory)
    entries_count = len(entries)
    for index, entry in enumerate(entries):
        connector = ELBOW if index == entries_count - 1 else TEE
        if entry.is_dir():
            add_directory(entry, index, entries_count, prefix, connector)
        else:
            add_file(entry, prefix, connector)

def add_directory(directory, index, entries_count, prefix, connector):
    tree.append(f"{prefix}{connector} {directory.name}{os.sep}")

    if index != entries_count - 1:
        prefix += PIPE_PREFIX
    else:
        prefix += SPACE_PREFIX

    tree_body(directory, prefix)

def add_file(file, prefix, connector):
    md5_hash = get_md5(file)
    tree.append(f"{prefix}{connector} {file.name} -> {md5_hash}")

def build_tree():
    tree_head()
    tree_body(root_dir)
    return tree

def generate():
    tree = build_tree()

    for entry in tree:
        print(entry)

generate()

This code generates a directory tree with file and directory names, as well as their MD5 hashes. Here's an example of the output that this script might produce, assuming the specified directory structure:
root_dir/ 
│
├── folder1/
│   ├── file1.txt -> d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
│   └── file2.txt -> 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
│
└── folder2/
    ├── file3.txt -> 6dcd4ce23d88e2ee9568ba546c007c63
    └── file4.txt -> d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e

How can the tree_body() function be converted from a recursive implementation to an iterative one?
I have tried many methods and found it difficult to print in the correct order.
I don't know what the correct approach for designing the algorithm for this problem looks like.

why do you want it to iterative?

You can push and pop from a stack to make the code iterative. I see no benefits tho.

@AlbinPaul I have tried both the map and stack methods. Iteration is easy, but it's difficult to output at the correct levels. As for the benefits, I don't want recursion in my code.

Honestly, this is a perfect fit for recursion. Reworking it to an iterative solution will just be uglier: use an explicit stack instead of the call stack provided by Python. If you’re working with trees, I’d suggest getting comfortable with recursion - it’s pretty core to many of the algorithms on tree structures.

"I don't want recursion in my code": bad decision. Instead of using the stack that is perfectly fit for such mechanics you'll find yourself with your own implementation of a stack just to implement the same algorithm but avoid calling it "recursion".

os.walk already does  it and uses os.scan in background

I finally implemented it, using a stack to simulate recursion. The principle is to perform a preorder traversal of an n-ary tree, which actually allows control over any previous stack position I want.
This is also a great exercise in converting recursion to iteration.
Additionally, using os.path and os.sep helps abstract the differences between operating systems.
import os
import re
import hashlib

PIPE = "│"
ELBOW = "└──"
TEE = "├──"
PIPE_PREFIX = "│   "
SPACE_PREFIX = "    "

class DirectoryTree:
    def __init__(self, root_dir):
        self._generator = _TreeGenerator(root_dir)

    def generate(self):
        tree = self._generator.build_tree()
        for entry in tree:
            print(entry)

class _TreeGenerator:
    def __init__(self, root_dir):
        self._root_dir = root_dir
        self._tree = []

    def build_tree(self):
        self._tree_head()
        self._tree_body(self._root_dir)
        return self._tree

    def _extract_number(self, file_name):
        match = re.search(r"\d+", file_name)
        return int(match.group()) if match else float("inf")

    def _get_md5(self, file_path):
        hasher = hashlib.md5()
        with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
            for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(8192), b""):
                hasher.update(chunk)
        return hasher.hexdigest()

    def _get_entries(self, folder):
        with os.scandir(folder) as entries:
            if entries is None:
                return None
            entries = list(entries)
            entries = [entry for entry in entries if entry.name != ".DS_Store"]
            entries = sorted(entries, key = lambda entry: self._extract_number(entry.name))
        return entries

    def _tree_head(self):
        self._tree.append(f"{os.path.basename(self._root_dir)}{os.sep}")
        self._tree.append(PIPE)

    def _tree_body(self, folder):
        folder, prefix, offset = folder, "", 0
        stack = [[folder, prefix, offset]]
        has_folder = False

        while stack:
            folder, prefix, offset = stack[-1]
            entries = self._get_entries(folder)
            if entries is None:
                stack = stack[:-1]
                break
            has_folder = False
            inner_folder = None

            for index, entry in enumerate(entries[offset:]):
                connector = ELBOW if i == len(entries[offset:]) - 1 else TEE
                if entry.is_dir():
                    self._tree.append(f"{prefix}{connector} {entry.name}{os.sep}")
                    if index != len(entries[offset:]) - 1:
                        prefix += PIPE_PREFIX
                    else:
                        prefix += SPACE_PREFIX
                    has_folder = True
                    inner_folder = entry
                    stack[-1][2] = offset + index + 1
                    break
                else:
                    md5_hash = self._get_md5(entry)
                    self._tree.append(f"{prefix}{connector} {entry.name} -> {md5_hash}")

            if has_folder:
                stack.append([inner_folder, prefix, 0])
            else:
                stack = stack[:-1]
                if self._tree[-1] != prefix.rstrip():
                    self._tree.append(prefix.rstrip())

tree = DirectoryTree("")
tree.generate()

print:
XX/
│
├── XXX/
│   ├── XXX 1 -> 887100ba4373eebfed52ee1f973161de
│   ├── XXX 2 -> 22fbcce00751c1c51fbd94e83e124fbb
│   ├── XXXX/
│   │   ├── XXXXX.pdf -> f45621b992b922009f4db4422abd6fe4
│   │   └── XXXXX.pdf -> d9cab932175d1e69709291000fa8ffa3
│   │
│   └── XXXX/
│
└── XXX.txt

If you want to add a -L feature, change the data structure to [[folder, prefix, offset, level]], then:
folder, prefix, offset, level = folder, "", 0, 1
stack = [[folder, prefix, offset, level]]
...
while stack:
    folder, prefix, offset, level = stack[-1]
    ...
    if entry.is_dir():
        self._tree.append(f"{prefix}{connector} {entry.name}{os.sep}")
        if level == x:
            continue
        else:
            if index != len(entries[offset:]) - 1:
                prefix += PIPE_PREFIX
...
if has_folder:
   stack.append([inner_folder, prefix, 0, level])
else:
...

Where x is the desired level.

Here is a stack-based approach that does not rely on recursion -
import os

def tree(init):
  stack = list((p, 0) for p in os.scandir(init))
  while stack:
    path, level = stack.pop()
    yield path, level
    if path.is_dir():
      stack.extend([(p, level + 1) for p in os.scandir(path)])

tree is a generator, with which we can easily implement md5_tree -
import hashlib

TEE = "├──"
PIPE_PREFIX = "│   "

def md5_tree(init):
  for path, level in tree(init):
    print(
      PIPE_PREFIX * level +
      TEE + 
      path.name +
      ('/' if path.is_dir() else " -> " + md5(path))
    )

def md5(path):
  with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    return hashlib.md5(f.read()).hexdigest()

Call md5_tree with an input path to see the result -
md5_tree(".")

Generators make it easy to intuitively filter elements, such as .DS_Store -
def md5_tree(init):
  for path, level in tree(init):
    if path.name == ".DS_Store": continue # filter
    print(...)

If you prefer not to use the generator, simply replace yield with your print statement -
def tree(init):
  stack = list((p, 0) for p in os.scandir(init))
  while stack:
    path, level = stack.pop()
    print(
      PIPE_PREFIX * level +
      TEE + 
      path.name +
      ('/' if path.is_dir() else " -> " + md5(path))
    )
    if path.is_dir():
      stack.extend([(p, level + 1) for p in os.scandir(path)])

os.scandir returns directory contents in arbitrary order. You can sort them using sorted. We are using a stack to order the output, so remember to sort using reverse=True -
def tree(init):
  stack = list((p, 0) for p in sorted(os.scandir(init), key=str, reverse=True))
  while stack:
    path, level = stack.pop()
    yield path, level
    if path.is_dir():
      stack.extend([(p, level + 1) for p in sorted(os.scandir(path), key=str, reverse=True)])


Got it, it's actually just the preorder traversal of an n-ary tree.

Yes, the preorder traversal can be written with or without recursion. Can you explain how this post does not answer your question? The code in your deleted answer added much complexity.

Try a directory class as a dicretory, like (in pseudo code):
Class DirBody():
    def __init__(self, name, depth):
        self.name = name
        self.depth = depth
        self.childDir = []
        self.childFile = []
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.printDirs() + "\n"+self.printFiles()
    def printDirs(self) -> str:
        pass
    def printFiles(self) -> str:
        pass

and you could walk every dir as a object and his sub_object.
